# Change Ssh Port From 22 to 2222 on Debian 10 "Buster"

Tags: debian, systemd, sshd

Trying here, without success, change the `sshd` port from 22 to 2222 on Debian 10 "Buster".

Already tried changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` line from `# Port 22` to `Port 2222`, reboot machine, but it didn't worked out.

Already tried changing `/etc/services` `ssh` column from `22` to `2222`, disabled then reenabled `sshd.service`, allowed it on `iptables` and `ufw` and it keeps on port 22.

Any idea about how to change `ssh` port 22 to 2222?

Comment: What have to done to see if sshd is listening on `:2222`? Is `ssh.socket` systemd unit disabled?

Comment: How are you verifying that you are connecting to what port? Are you using `ssh user@host -p 2222` to connect?

Comment: `Port 2222` not `port 2222` right ?

Comment: SELinux doesn't allow it probably. You need the use `semanage` to fix it

Comment: Checked via `nmap` command, yes, tried with `ssh -p 2222 user@host` with no success and yes, `Port 2222` instead of `port 2222`.

Comment: Just changing the `Port` in `sshd_config` worked for me. Please add the output of `egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` (cleared of any sensitive stuff) to your Q. BTW, you should _never_ modify `/etc/services` -- that's only the business of IANA (and of misguided distro maintainers ;-)).

Comment: "but it didn't worked out" What actually happens when you change the port number in sshd_config and restart sshd? Do you get errors? Does sshd fail to start? How do you know it didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Just checked here that didn't added `Port 2222` and commented out `Port 22` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Now it all seems to be clear and running on port 2222, my mistake.